# error: failed to push some refs to 'origin'

Tags: git, git-push

This command `git push -u origin master` outputs the following errors:

```
error: failed to push some refs to 'origin'

error: src refspec master does not match any
```

I have tried this too:

```
git add .
git commit -am "initial commit"
git push -u origin master
```

Then the output:

```
fatal: 'origin' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit-push%5D+fatal%3A+%27origin%27+does+not+appear+to+be+a+git+repository

Comment: @phd: according to the comment he made under my answer, he does have an origin. Sibasankar should [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/65669316/edit) the question to reflect that.

Comment: @DaemonPainter Yes, the linked dup answers exactly that. Sibasankar should have search before asking.

Comment: but the solution is to add an origin. He already _has_ an origin, see the comment under my answer.

Answer (score 2):

You have no origin. Run `git remote` to prove that [[ref](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-remote)].

Add a new origin with `git remote add origin <path to remote repository>`.

Comment: (envy) E:\Python-practice\MyDojo>git remote  
origin
  
(envy) E:\Python-practice\MyDojo>git remote add origin E:/Python-practice/MyDojo/.git/  
error: remote origin already exists.

This is what I got. Origin already exist.

Comment: So you are using a local remote somewhere else on the system. Make sure that `/` and `\ ` are not colliding and causing the issue, will you?